# Is there any way of adding the exact same login options of StackExchange websites in a Drupal 7 site?

Tags: 7, users

I think that the title is pretty descriptive but I would like to be as detailed as possible so let me list all the login options that I would like my drupal site to have available:

- Open ID
- Stack Exchange
- Facebook
- Yahoo
- Gmail
- Wordpress
- Blogger
- AOL
- Google Profile
- Verisign (optional)
- LiveJournal (optional)
- Clickpass (optional)
- ClaimID (optional)

So, is there any solution to implement this in a Drupal 7 website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements are pretty big, to say the least!

That being said, I have used [Janrain (now named rpx) module](http://drupal.org/project/rpx) with great success in the past.

It can easily implement many of the services on your list in a drupal site.  The only con is that it depends on having an account on  3rd party code provider's site, I think they act as a gateway so it is less efficient than a well-built custom solution performance-wise,  ***but***  they  offer *many* features and the service they provide works very well out of the box with very little configuration.

I highly recommend it for anyone needing 3rd party login services in their app.

Answer (score 2):

StackExchange uses the [JavaScript OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/). Drupal can use the JavaScript OpenID Selector by means of the [OpenID Selector](http://drupal.org/project/openid_selector) module.

Comment: Just tried OpenID Selector -- works amazingly, and no need for a 3rd party provider.